# Javascript eval simplification

Tags: javascript, google-maps, eval

I am loading multiple Google maps in JavaScript, but the only way I was able to accomplish this in JavaScript was to use "eval".

I've read that `eval` is insecure. Can the following line be simplified or done another way?

```
eval('var map' + uin + ' = ' + 'new google.maps.Map(map_canvas, map_options);');
```

Comment: Advice: don't use `eval`.

Comment: Why do you think it's the only way to do it?

Comment: Familiarize yourself with the XY problem. http://goo.gl/taIqf

Comment: If it works in eval, it can be made working without it. What was your code without eval and what was the error ?

Comment: I don't really get it, why are you using eval at all, seems like just a variable assigment, and it makes no sense to do it that way ?

Comment: WTH is `uin`? Why don't you use an array?

Comment: Arrays are evil .... no wait, that was the other one ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var maps = {};
maps[uin] = new google.maps.Map(map_canvas, map_options)
```

Using objects is fun!

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to create a dynamic variable name.

How about creating an array of maps?

```
var maps  = [];

maps[ 0 ] = new google.maps.Map(map_canvas, map_options);

maps[ 1 ] = new google.maps.Map(map_canvas, map_options);
```

But it looks like you're using the same `map_canvas` for all these maps – that's probably going to screw something up.